# Making servers in F#

Tags: .net, f#, microservices

What's the best (or easiest) way to create standalone microservices like HTTP or socket servers in F#? Would you use Suave, or just raw F# + libraries? Are there good examples of those?

Comment: Voted to close as off-topic (http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). I recommend asking this type of questions on the F# Foundation Slack - http://fsharp.org/guides/slack/ (#general or #beginner channels are full of great and helpful F# devs)

Comment: Join the Foundation to get access to the slack...